# Too many restrictions while writing a question on Stack Overflow

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, question-quality

I find that there are too many restrictions in formulating questions on Stack Overflow. This site is not very forgiving, at least for some (I think nervous) people who quickly take away our points. I'd like to remind all that Stack Overflow is advertised as "for professional and enthusiast programmers" so I think it sounds very universal. Maybe the idea with only a small number of moderators would be better?

Comment: Don't stop reading the FAQ at that line. Read it completely. The restrictions are spelled out.

Comment: I'm so sorry but I didn't read any FAQ and not planning. I'm interested in programmin' not in weird rules!

Comment: Well, there you go. If you don't even want to read the rules, why are you whining and complaining? Familiarize yourself with them, and you won't run into any restrictions.

Comment: For example, why this question got so many negative poins, however it's valid on meta. You may not agree with my opinion but not with correctness of this question!

Comment: Duh. That's why you should **read the FAQ**, [where it says](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#vote-differences) *> Voting here works a bit differently from other Stack Exchange sites. On Meta Stack Overflow, voting is often used to express agreement or disagreement, not to point out a lack of quality or helpfulness*

Comment: ok :) sorry - this place is actulally very special, and this may be even very good from my point of view.

Comment: Isn't programming **full of weird rules**??

Comment: @surfasb, yes but we do not have a reverse implication - for example Koran, Torah, Mein Kampf etc. are far from good programming style.

Comment: Not reverse implication, but self conscious. There is no reason to feel down when Stack Overflow gives you unlimited continues. Heck it even comes with a Strategy Guide, **for free**.

Answer (score 12):

I agree the question closing that you are probably referring to (now deleted) was a bit harsh.

But generally, the narrow focus on objective, answerable questions is what makes Stack Overflow great. You will notice the site is still of decent quality despite 2.1 million questions. Strict quality control, and allowing users to vote and close questions, is an essential part of it.

Comment: Maybe you're right but nevertheless closing, many questions remains not very interesting and this action often is very controversial.
I think that when we're looking for well-defined problem we don't have problem with filtering topics thanks to the search engine.

Comment: @ninjaaa: *Not very interesting* is not a close reason, we never close questions because they don't interest. Please note that questions are not only closed, but the worst of them (that really are not useful in any way) also get deleted. For example, jokes like programming on a boat in extreme weather conditions where the question is more about the extreme weather than about programming. These kind of questions don't show up in your search engine at all, nor do they appear in the question lists...

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> I find that there are too many restrictions in formulating questions on Stack Overflow.

Please note that the most important parts of the Stack Overflow FAQ related to asking questions are:

> 1. Stack Overflow is for professional and enthusiast programmers, people who write code...
> 2. You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.
>
> — [Extract from the FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq)

Note how all the rest of "What kind of questions [can I ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#questions) and [should I not ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask)" just adds more explanation; the main idea is a Q&A site where Programmers can actually *learn* about coding and so on.

If I randomly quote `it is a rant disguised as a question: “______ sucks, am I right?”`, then you can clearly see that if you rant about something you won't learn anything from it. We have these lines for people that actually love ranting about things and don't see that (2) actually covers this.

---

You continued:

> This site is not very forgiving, at least for some people who quickly take away our points.

As I noted in the previous part, our network is all about learning. One of the best ways to learn to use our site is from your own mistakes, we're not trying to punish you but we're instead trying to maintain quality. See it like a child touching something hot, he won't do it again and later learn that something is cooking...

So, it is best to **just try it** and you will learn in either way.

---

You suggested:

> Maybe the idea with only a small number of moderators would be better?

As Pekka [mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/108074/too-many-restrictions-while-writing-a-question-on-stack-overflow/108075#108075), maintenance of our quality is essential or we wouldn't have such a big community. You can read [more about moderators](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) if you want to know why they exists, what they do and which people get chosen to be them. But also [note that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) anyone from 2000 reputation can edit and anyone from 3000 reputation can vote to close a question, maintenance mostly happens collaboratively.

Don't underestimate this, a lot of not real questions are closed and even deleted. Due to the amount of moderators and high reputation units this kind of content is removed *before* you get to see it. This is not only about questions, but also about floods of answers that say "I have this problem too" as well as advertisements and what else. Sometimes, it's necessary to do some house cleaning...